# Swift dynamic tableview height based on content

Tags: swift, tableview

Did a search and the only thing I can find on here are for dynamic cell heights. I'm new to swift, and I'd like to have a tableview where the height of the tableview adjusts according to the number of rows. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason to do this but...

You must know how many items are in the tableview since it's your datasource (presumably whatever number you're returning in `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection`.

So you could adjust the size like so:

```
let totalSizeOfCells = (tableView.rowHeight * CGFloat(numOfItems.count))
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, totalSizeOfCells)
```

Where `numOfItems.count` is the number of cells you have.

Comment: this doesn't seem to affect the tableview height at all. The reason I'm using this is because I will have a vc with multiple stacked tableviews with a variable number of rows