# Swift dynamic tableview height

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableView which I want to size dynamically in height depending on how many cells are there (and to pull/push all views underneath it)

I've tried to archieve this by putting it in a StackView, but TableView content doesn't show unless I give it a fixed height constraint, which is opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Also tried this [Swift dynamic tableview height based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189482/swift-dynamic-tableview-height-based-on-content) with no change, as the comment from OP said too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my first question is: _why?_

Comment: Because if I have a tableview, with the height of let's say 5 cells without scroll, and some other content underneath it, it's good when it has all 5 cells filled, or when it has none (I hide it), but if it has 1 or 2 cells there's a lot of blank white space.

Comment: that is still not quite clear why you don't want to add the _other_ content to your tableview in a cell?

Answer (score 0):

Set table frame or table height Constraint outlet with table content size means set the table view height constraint equal to its content size after the table view has done the loading.

```
tableHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
```